# Excel numbers incorrectly multiplied by 1000

Tags: excel, format, number-formatting

I have an issue with Excel file obtained from a SAP application. Examples below show numbers on the left which I have in SAP and are real, and the **numbers enclosed in brackets** are what I get in the Excel file:

- 15.6 (15600)
- 11.52 (11520)
- 5.94 (5940)
- 140 (140)
- 770 (770)
- 1 (1000)
- 21 (21000)

Does anyone know which formula I should use? Format is general and Excel is using `.` as separator.

**UPDATE:** In SAP I have `2,194,348.00`, where comma is for 1000 and dot for decimals.

Comment: Can you please check the number settings in Windows? I belive the decimal is set to ',' (coma) and the tousans separator is '.' (dot). If yes, you have to move the number into a text field in ABAP, replace the dot with come (TRANSLATE...) and start the Excel export after that.

Comment: Can you check your profile? Go to menu 'User Profile' / 'Own Data' and click on 'Defaults' tab. You will see your decimal notation.

Comment: I checked win10 settings, my decimal is se to dot.

Comment: **How** do you export? This is the mail question. What technique do you use? Give the code

Comment: Point is I am not doing exports, I am given those exports. However I solved the problem. I am importing the excel as .txt file and there I can change comma, dot and it works.